# How to allow null joined results in linq?

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq

I have the following query:

```
var query = from a in context.TableA
            where (a.P1 == param1 || a.P2 == param2)
            join b in context.TableB
            on a.Id equals b.aId
            into bValues
            from b in bValues.DefaultIfEmpty().Where(bSubQ => bSubQ.X == (a.Y == param1 ? param2: param1))
            join c in context.TableC
            on b.cId equals c.Id
            into cValues
            from c in cValues.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                   A = a,
                   B = b,
                   C= c
             };
```

I have a table (TableA) which always has entries with the ids for the matched parameters param1 and param2, so there should always be two results.

However, I want to then say "for each of these results, check if there's a joined result in table B and if there is make sure that the property X on table B is the opposite parameter. If not, give me null for B in the result. Then, if there is a found match in table B, look in table C for a joined result and again, if it's not found set C as null".

Can I do this all in one query or do I need to seperate it out? I am also open to a function in postgresql if that makes it easier.

Edit: I'm struggling to explain this, maybe this helper function will explain what I want to combine into one query:

```
private static List<ResultTemp> TempGetResultTODODelete(DbContext context, long param1, long param2)
{
    var aResults= context.TableA
        .Where(a => (a.Id == param1 || a.Id == param2)
        .Take(2).ToList();

    var aIds = aResults.Select(a => a.Id).ToList();
    var bResults = context.TableB
        .Where(c => aIds.Contains(b.aId))
        .ToList();

    var bIds = bResults.Where(b => b.X == 
         (a.Y == param1 ? param2: param1)
               .Select(b => b.X)
               .ToList();

    var c = context.TableC
              .Where(c => bIds.Contains(c.Id))
              .FirstOrDefault();

    var result = new List<ResultTemp>();

    foreach(var a in aResults)
    {
        result.Add(new ResultTemp
        {
            A = a,
            B = bResults.Where(b => b.aId == b.Id).FirstOrDefault(),
            C = c
        });
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What's the issue with your query?

Comment: When table B has results that don't match the where query I get no results for that A entry

Comment: Ah, I see now. Just move `DefaultIfEmpty` after `Where`.

Comment: *facepalm* nice one thanks that fixed it